# Unix: Split a file into two based on matched string

Tags: bash, unix, sed, awk, grep

I want to split a file into two, but cannot find a way to do this.

```
Master.txt
Happy Birthday to you!  [[#HAPPY]]
Stop it.  [[#COMMAND]]
Make a U-turn. [[#COMMAND]]
```

I want to split into two files, with the 2nd file starting when it matches the regex pattern `[[#`

```
Output1.txt
Happy Birthday to you!
Stop it.
Make a U-turn.

Output2.txt
[[#HAPPY]]
[[#COMMAND]]
[[#COMMAND]]
```

I've tried using awk:

```
awk -v RS="[[#*" '{ print $0 > "temp" NR }'
```

but it doesn't give my desired output -- any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way with `GNU awk`:

```
awk -v RS='\\[\\[#|\n' 'NR%2{print $0>"Output1.txt";next}{print "[[#"$0>"Output2.txt"}' master
```

#### Test:

```
$ ls
master

$ cat master 
Happy Birthday to you!  [[#HAPPY]]
Stop it.  [[#COMMAND]]
Make a U-turn. [[#COMMAND]]

$ awk -v RS='\\[\\[#|\n' 'NR%2{print $0>"Output1.txt";next}{print "[[#"$0>"Output2.txt"}' master

$ ls
master  Output1.txt  Output2.txt

$ head Out*
==> Output1.txt <==
Happy Birthday to you!  
Stop it.  
Make a U-turn. 

==> Output2.txt <==
[[#HAPPY]]
[[#COMMAND]]
[[#COMMAND]]
```

Comment: super duper, I was thinking on same line but you were too quick.

Comment: You can reduce the print calls ,see my answer. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

A pure `bash` solution might be a little slower, but is very readable:

```
while read line; do
    [[ $line =~ (.*)(\[\[#.*]]) ]]
    printf "%s" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" >&3
    printf "%s" "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" >&4
done 3> output1.txt 4> output2.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
you can write small script like this…
#!/bin/ksh

sed -i -e 's/ \[\[#/,\[\[#/' $1

cut -d, -f1 $1 > $1.part1
cut -d, -f2 $1 > $1.part2    
---------------------------------------------
```

OR…use multi-command line

```
# sed -i -e 's/ \[\[#/,\[\[#/' Master.txt ; cut -d, -f1 Master.txt > output1.txt ; cut -d, -f1 Master.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: be carefull, you assume that `,` is not used in first part of text and use it to cut but it's maybe not the case in the full file.

Answer (score 0):

Simpler in `sed`, IMHO:

```
$ sed 's/^\([^[]*\).*/\1/' Master.txt > Output1.txt
$ sed 's/^[^[]*//'         Master.txt > Output2.txt
```

Comment: idea is good but does not reply to specific request. it mention to separe string after `[[#` not `[`

Comment: Same thing for the sample input file.

Comment: this is a sample but you could have `Happy day to you [and your wife]!  [[#HAPPY]]` that will fail. It is just "assume" that there is no `[[#` in first part of the line.

Comment: If this case can occur, it should be treated in the sample input/output.

Comment: so why does he mention `[[#` if `[` is enough. Sample not always show every case possible.  If constraint is reduce, your code works

Comment: Probably overspecification. If a three character separator is, in fact, needed, then two character substrings of it should be used in the sample input to defeat solutions like mine.

Answer (score 0):

No need for `gnu awk`, this should work for any `awk`

```
awk -F'\\[\\[#' '{print $1>"Output1.txt";print "[[#"$2>"Output2.txt"}' Master.txt
```

```
cat Output1.txt
Happy Birthday to you!
Stop it.
Make a U-turn.
```

```
cat Output2.txt
[[#HAPPY]]
[[#COMMAND]]
[[#COMMAND]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n 's/\[\[#/\
&/;P
/\n/ {s/.*\n//;H;}
$ {x;s/\n//;w Output2.txt
  }' YourFile > Output1.txt
```

in 1 sed but awk is better suite for this task

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you(GNU sed):

```
sed -n 's/\[\[#/\n&/;P;s/.*\n//w file3' file1 >file2
```